# PHP - Error de petición

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
include_once("database.php");
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
if (isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($request->id));
    //Devuelve un empleado
    $sql = "SELECT id,name,email,hentrada_con,minentrada_con,hsalida_con,minsalida_con FROM empleados WHERE id = " . $id;
    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo json_encode($row);
    } else {
        http_response_code(404);
    }
}
```

Lo que pretendo hacer con él es lo siguiente:

La aplicación emite un listado de empleados. A su vez, cada empleado tiene un botón asignado en función de su id, que, al pulsarlo, carga una página con los valores que se están pidiendo en este código PHP. Ese valor id que procede de otra petición es el que debe de recoger este fragmento de código para hacer la correspondiente consulta.
Hasta donde he podido comprobar, en el front no hay problema, ya que el método asociado recoge correctamente el id de la anterior petición como parámetro.

Me queda saber si este código es correcto o no, ya que de no serlo, será algo muy específico de la conexión o por el estilo, por lo que quiero descartar los sospechosos más evidentes.

Por tanto, pretendo conocer si la sintaxis de este código es correcta.

Gracias por adelantado.

**ACTUALIZACION:**Parece que el problema estaría aquí

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

El método no parece ser el adecuado para solicitar el id. ¿Cuál sería entonces?

Answer (score 0):

Solo funciona si el metodo de solicitud es `POST` de tipo `contentType: 'text/json'`

```
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Dicho esto:

```
<?php
include_once("database.php");

//Si no envian los  datos por el body
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
    http_response_code(405);
    die();
}  

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    
//Si no envian el id
if (!isset($request->id) ) {
    http_response_code(400);
    die();
}

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($request->id));

//Devuelve un empleado
$sql = "SELECT id,name,email,hentrada_con,minentrada_con,hsalida_con,minsalida_con FROM empleados WHERE id = " . $id;
if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode($row);
} else {
    //Si algo va mal error de tu parte  
    http_response_code(500);
}
?>
```

Ahora Segun que codigo de error devuelva . podras saber que esta pasando

> 400 Bad Request El servidor no puede o no procesará la solicitud
> debido a algo que se percibe como un error del cliente (p. ej.,
> sintaxis de solicitud mal formada, marco de mensaje de solicitud no
> válido o enrutamiento de solicitud engañoso).
>
> 405 Method Not Allowed El servidor conoce el método de solicitud, pero
> el recurso de destino no lo admite. Por ejemplo, es posible que una
> API no permita realizar llamadas DELETEpara eliminar un recurso.
>
> 400 Bad Request El servidor no puede o no procesará la solicitud
> debido a algo que se percibe como un error del cliente (p. ej.,
> sintaxis de solicitud mal formada, marco de mensaje de solicitud no
> válido o enrutamiento de solicitud engañoso).
>
> 200 OK La solicitud tuvo éxito. El significado del resultado de
> "éxito" depende del método HTTP:
>
> GET: el recurso se ha obtenido y transmitido en el cuerpo del mensaje.
> HEAD: Los encabezados de representación se incluyen en la respuesta
> sin ningún cuerpo de mensaje. PUTo POST: El recurso que describe el
> resultado de la acción se transmite en el cuerpo del mensaje. TRACE:
> El cuerpo del mensaje contiene el mensaje de solicitud tal como lo
> recibió el servidor. 201 Created

Answer (score 0):

como haces la peticion a la api?
con ajax? desde una app  android? con ajax no he necesitado usar input ya que entra como *POST*, con peticiones desde android, si fue necesario usar *php://input*
podrias hacer un log.txt con el contenido de :

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: Creo que la petición se hace por GET, si no me equivoco. En el siguiente enlace puedes ver el código del front, incluida la api (en castellano quité la pregunta porque nadie me contestaba) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74557060/angular-php-screen-output-error-sql-request-empty

Comment: podes hacer un log.txt deloque recibis?

Comment: ``/user-detail.php/' +id``
esta seria tu peticion? como capturas id?
``/user-detail.php/?id=' +id``
yo te puedo ayudar en php, pero necesitomas datos, por ejemplo que estas recibiendo en la peticion.
hace un *logfile*, donde guardes todos lso datos dela peticion para comprobar que realmente este recibiendo lo que deberias

Comment: si esta implementando con *GET* deberias tomar la varible ``$_GET`` para identificar el *id*